# ratio test to find series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We have a series

$$b_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(3n^3+1)^36^n}{3(n!)}$$

I assume to use positive ratio test $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ to find if it's convergent.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}&=\frac{(3n^3+2)^36^{n+1}}{3(n+1)!} \cdot
\frac{3(n!)}{(3n^3+1)^36^n}\\
&=\frac{6(3n^3+2)^3}{(3n^3+1)^3(n+1)}
\end{align}
$$

What method do I then use to then to prove that it's sequence converges to limit 0?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} =\frac{6(3n^3+2)^3}{(3n^3+1)^3(n+1)} = \frac{6 (3+\frac 2n)^3}{(3+\frac 1n )^3 (n+1)} \to \frac{6 \cdot 27}{27(n+1)} =0$$

Hence, series converges.

Comment: The result is correct but the way to express is a little confusing since you start with th elim symbol and then use $\to$ for  apartial limit and finally an equal sign, it should be better $$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} =\frac{6(3n^3+2)^3}{(3n^3+1)^3(n+1)} = \frac{6 (3+\frac 2n)^3}{(3+\frac 1n )^3 (n+1)} \to \frac{6 \cdot 27}{27\cdot \infty} =0$$

Answer (score 1):

one factor is given by $$\frac{n^9\left(3+\frac{2}{n^3}\right)^3}{n^9\left(3+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the polynomial term in negligeble since by ratio test it gives a constant term indeed

$$\frac{ (3(n+1)^3+1)^3 }{(3n^3+1)^3}\to 1$$

thus you can consider the leading term $c_n=\frac{6^n}{n!}$

$$\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}=\frac{6^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{6^n}=\frac{6}{n+1}\to 0$$

thus $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\to0$ and the given series converges.